# why my VPS says my nginx status is dead, disabled, error block UFW, but the sites are still UP?

Tags: nginx, webmin, virtualmin

I myself can execute any command with respect to the nginx service. but the pid is still in /run/nginx.pid :-D which shows that the process is running and I can still access the sites. but the dead service is scary and quiet, and I do not even need to say that if I need to restart nginx, I will not be able to because I can not!

I really appreciate your help.

systemctl status nginx:

```
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
root@vps1:~# /etc/init.d/nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-08-23 12:31:26 WEST; 10h ago
  Process: 29455 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30170 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30167 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4178 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

journalctl -xe

```
Aug 23 22:51:18 vps1 saslauthd[1550]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=amphidisc@vps.FQDN.com] [service=smtp] [realm=vps.FQDN
Aug 23 22:51:18 vps1 postfix/smtpd[32123]: warning: unknown[181.214.206.123]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Aug 23 22:51:19 vps1 postfix/smtpd[32123]: disconnect from unknown[181.214.206.123] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Aug 23 22:51:23 vps1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:21:2:d33:97:51a:d74:a4:24:01:ef:61:03:00 SRC=124.16.131.250 DST=100.47.84.180 LEN=60 T
Aug 23 22:51:25 vps1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:21:2:d33:97:51a:d74:a4:24:01:ef:61:03:00 SRC=78.128.112.18 DST=100.47.84.180 LEN=40 TO
Aug 23 22:51:25 vps1 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Aug 23 22:51:25 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:25 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:26 vps1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:21:2:d33:97:51a:d74:a4:24:01:ef:61:03:00 SRC=82.221.105.7 DST=100.47.84.180 LEN=44 TOS
Aug 23 22:51:26 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:26 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:26 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:26 vps1 nginx[3310]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.47.84.180:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 23 22:51:27 vps1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:21:2:d33:97:51a:d74:a4:24:01:ef:61:03:00 SRC=124.16.131.250 DST=100.47.84.180 LEN=60 T
```

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2018/08/23 12:26:41 [emerg] 29481#29481: invalid number of arguments in "fastcgi_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf:32
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:31:24 [emerg] 30170#30170: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:32:11 [emerg] 30262#30262: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 12:34:43 [emerg] 31749#31749: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:44:39 [emerg] 31550#31550: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:47:10 [emerg] 31757#31757: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:49:41 [emerg] 31874#31874: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:52:11 [emerg] 32122#32122: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 21:54:42 [emerg] 32204#32204: still could not bind()
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: bind() to 54.71.93.142:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/08/23 22:51:25 [emerg] 3310#3310: still could not bind()
```

Answer (score 0):

You started nginx manually, outside of systemd. This is why systemd can't start it again. You can simply kill the manually started nginx and then you will be able to restart the service properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. But, I can not interpret this event, because it accuses block error by UFW, and because I stopped the UFW I could start the service normally? with the same command that was prevented from using> service nginx Start, I did not even need to restart, I'm scared, I created a scrip with cronjob every 5 min. which makes a grep with the output of nginx status, if it finds "dead", disable UFW, start nginx, sleep 6 sec. echo "yes" | enable ufw, I'm scared of it!

Comment: I see nothing relevant to ufw here. Why do you start and stop ufw?

Comment: It's like I said before, I tried to `stop/start/restart` the service in every way `... /etc/init.d/ngi...` `/usr/sbin/ngi...` `systemctl star...` `service ngi...` nothing it worked, and they all said the same error I posted in the ask .. UFW block, so I did: `ufw disable`, and simply and simply nginx started with service nginx start and the status is back `active (running)` now